# Animated armor homebrew PC for newbie game

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players, homebrew

My friends and I are starting the basic starter set but I am very uninterested in the races. If I used the [animated armor race](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Animated_Armor_(5e_Race)) would I mess up the game and make things a lot more complex? We are doing homebrew but we are all new to this and I don't want to complicate things. So how hard would it be for me to make this work with my character as animated armor in 5e with the guidelines of the race?

Comment: Have you reviewed [the Unearthed Arcana Warforged race](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Eberron_v1.pdf) on the WoTC web site?

Comment: PSA/warning: dandwiki is very abundant in homebrew -- fan-made creations -- which includes the armor you've linked to. (You can tell because at the bottom it says: "Back to Main Page → **5e Homebrew** → Races", emphasis added.) The homebrew on dandwiki effectively comes without warranty: it may be very poorly authored (such as missing or poorly defining important details), overly powerful, overly weak, or entirely broken. Using it is very much a "make sure you know what you're doing" scenario; I suggest you as a newbie avoid dandwiki.

Comment: okay thank you, i figured that i shouldnt go off of the website

Comment: Or, if this really is your group's first time, avoid homebrewing until you get a hang of the game. Using the tropes of Dwarves, Elves and Humans and other races, help get your feet wet at first. Then you can homebrew as much as you want.

Answer (score 4):

A very common answer you're going to get with 5e questions is "ask your DM", and that's very appropriate here.  Mechanic effects aside, you'll need to check with your DM to ensure that this custom race will not violate any elements of the setting or story.

In regards to the technicals of the class, I see a few issues:

1. The AC is just listed as being "The same as [light/medium/heavy] armor", but there are multiple different ACs within each classification, so this would have to be resolved first and foremost.
2. There is no mention of whether animated armor can wear other armor (ie, can an anarmor shrink down to "small" size, and wear "medium" or "large" armor?).  Can they wear magic rings?
3. The race description makes no mention of a dex contributing to AC ("AC is the *same as* [light/medium/heavy] armor); this means that there is no way for an anarmor player to increase their AC as they level up.
4. Complete immunity to fire damage may be unbalanced, if it can be used after submerging in water, an unlimited number of times per day.
5. Complete immunity to poison and gas ("gas" is very vague) can also be very unbalanced.  Coupled with fire, that's two relatively common types of damage that a player can simply ignore from level 1.
6. The recharge ability is very vague.  How long must an anarmor recharge to gain full benefits?  What does "start to fall apart" mean?  How soon does that penalty kick in?  How can it be undone?
7. Being ageless and not requiring food, water, or air can remove certain common challenges and obstacles; this is another reason to check with your DM.

All in all, I can see how this race is very easy to abuse (ie, carting around jut enough water to "fully submerge" a small anarmor before battle for fire immunity, or concealing an anarmor player in a Bag of Holding since they don't need air, etc).  But, it ultimately falls to the individual players and the DM.

Comment: thank you, i have decided against it and going to go with another race.